# Как привязать событие "mouseleave" к двум классам

Tags: javascript, jquery

в DOM имеются такие элементы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка с классом `.btnchik`;
`<div>` с классом - `.btnchik-warn` и ид `#chik`.

Простая Задача (Уже реализована);
По наведению на кнопку, к `#chik` добавляется класс `show` (`display:block`);
Проще говоря `<div>` появляется...

Теперь мне, нужна помощь, по реализации такой задачи:
событие `mouseleave`, должно быть у `#chik` и `.btnchik`;

Объяснение: Когда курсор уходит с поля `#chik` либо `.btnchik`, срабатывает событие `mouseleave`, и у ид `#chik` удаляется класс - `show`, в моём случае **jQuery** (`.removeClass()`).

Скрипт **jQuery**, который мне удалось реализовать:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btnchik').on("mouseenter", function(){
    $('#chik').addClass('show');
    $('#chik').on("mouseleave", function(){
      $('#chik').removeClass('show');
    })
  });
});
```

p.s. Не обязательно **jQuery**, но особая благодарность что помощь осуществляется на нём.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так сложно, на Java-Script? Только CSS решение не подойдет?

```css
.menuitem       > div { display:  none; padding: 1em; background: silver; }
.menuitem:hover > div { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="menuitem">
  <button>Menu</button>
  <div>Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А серьёзно? Блин, не думал на css такое сделать, спасибо большое !